# Unable to reach style.css on localhost:8080

Tags: php, html, css, localhost, stylesheet

I have a copy of a current live sites code that I downloaded via FTP. I have set up XAMPP on my local machine and have confirmed that it is installed and working correctly (did a simple helloworld.php test).

I have localhost set up as localhost:8080 (default port 80 in use by IIS).

When I try and run the website locally though, I am unable to reach the css style sheet.

I have tried the following but none seems to work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/style/style.css" TYPE="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mySite/themes/style/style.css" TYPE="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/mySite/themes/style/style.css" TYPE="text/css">
```

The path to the style.css is correct and I have tripple checked that the style.css file is in the style folder.

In my style.css I have also changed for instance the background image reference to poin to local host, same as above. I tried all 3 variations as above as well

```
body {
    background: url(http://localhost/mySite/images/back.jpg) no-repeat fixed center   top;
 }
```

I have also connected to localhost:8080/phpmyadmin and copied across the live Database. I can access the content of the Database as well (the site uses a CMS system to display some parts of the website) and I can see all parts of the website formatted via the Database OK.

Opening the site on Firefox and using Firebug it says "There are no rules....."

Does anyone know why I am not able to access the style.css folder and how I can fix it?

Comment: What error does your console say? Like 404 or 403 or any other? Try opening the CSS file in your browser directly and see what error you rceive.

Comment: I guess your css file in the themes folder might be encrypted by the Windows as so, your site cannot access it. Ensure this, right click on themes under mySite folder > Choose properties > Click Advanced button > Uncheck Encrypt Contents to Secure data. And on clicking Ok, choose Apply changes to this folder, subfolders and files.

Comment: Navigating to the css folder using the link below works fine and I can see my css code there. No errors are shown 
http://localhost:8080/mySite/themes/style/style.css

I also checked the "Uncheck Encrypt Contents to Secure data." but this box was not ticked by default. 

From what I can tell the site is built on the PHP Nuke Framework. Is there anything else I may be missing? I checked the config.php files but nothing stood out at me in regards to the css files.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome open developer tools and check for any 404 errors under console tab.

Comment: OK dev tools gives a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". But kinda guessed that was what it would respond with as thats the problem Im having. For some reason the css cant be found.

Comment: Copy and the paste the URL which generates 404 error under developer tools.

Comment: Reference: http://s4.postimg.org/fx5zlbuwd/file.jpg. Red underline text will give you idea about what is the link for the file which is requested.

Comment: OK now I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
message: "Unexpected token }"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error

Comment: I applied the same reference to a JavaScript file I have and that seems to be working OK now (<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/mySite/includes/function_MM.js"></script>) but still no luck with the css. There are also no errors shown now in Chrome dev tools

Comment: Does your site have any ReWrite conditions defined using .htaccess?

Comment: No dont have any .htaccess files configured. I have LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so enabled. Will I need to create a .htaccess file? Anything in particular I need to include in it?

Answer (score 0):

open the page in the browser, View page source and click on the link of the style sheets , if that doesn't redirect on correct locations. Check the "href" link in the style sheet.

Comment: Thanks Vishvesh. I tried this but clicking on the style sheet link but directs me to the css file and I can see my code there.

Answer (score 0):

First, drop a html file or image file in your CSS folder then try to reference it from your home page using the href / src (as applicable) this will help you decide if there is some kind of restrictions on that CSS folder. Let me know your findings please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following problem: It can't load the latest changes in CSS. Css files are in the head element, and the styles are clearly being picked up by the .aspx page  Usually this is cache related. Try doing a hard refresh -- CTRL Shift R. Also, if you are using apache2, use the "-i" option. Files are not updating because they are cached. And if you cannot do this, change the **href="styles.css" into href="styles.css?v=version2"** (that's worked like a charm for my website when I faced the same issue). It would make the server think there is a new file, so then it updates the cache.

Thank me later